# Is there an xdg comliant DE independant "default-aplication-setter application"?

Tags: freedesktop, defaults, xdg

Topic is the question.

Requirements:

- FOSS of course
- Independant of desktop environments
- is compliant with the [Association between MIME types and applications](http://standards.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.html) standard
- Has optionally a neat GUI (my application uses mimeapps.list and I want to refer my user to a userfriendly way to change default apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the cli tool. A GUI would still be nice to have...

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype foo.jpg                # Get the mimetype of the file
image/jpeg
$ xdg-mime default gwenview.desktop image/jpeg   # Set a new association
```